# How can I change the Facebook page plugin's fontsize?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change facebook plugin font size inside an iframe.
 [want to change text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTICV.png)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       setTimeout(function() { 
       $('._58jw p').css('font-size', '12px');
     }, 6000);  });
```

Now, I'm using this script but this code is not working.

Comment: Is it within an iframe? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, It is within an iframe. It's nothing errors in the console.Thanks!

Comment: have you got access to iframe's contentWindow script?

Comment: If it's within an iframe then it's likely they will be blocking cross domain requests to it. Unfortunately you can't change the font size.

Comment: You can't normally access iframes from outside the iframe.

Comment: Can you see the image of my problem?
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTICV.png]

Comment: @YMA yes, I see the problem, but since it's an `iframe`, you can't change the font size.

Comment: @Jeff Huijsmans Thanks!
If you known other way. Can you show me code or tutorial link?